# Is there a difference between intermittent time series and sparse time series?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

In the context of demand forecasting, when it comes to items with low/infrequent sales, I've come across two different ways of describing them: Intermittent demand and sparse demand.

Are these two ways of describing the same thing or is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

They are nearly synonyms ... although if you had a series like 1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,2   .this might be better define as sparse but with no missing values i.e. '0's' thus it is not intermittent because observations are being recorded at fixed intervals .It is somewhat ambiguous to me because 1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,3,1,0,1,1,2 is also recorded at fixed intervals of time.

Comment: Yes, "sparse" and "intermittent" demand appear to be used synonymously--but not in the way suggested by your examples.  They are characterized by *random, irregular times* of demand for a product.  One might record such data as a sequence of (time, amount) pairs where the times regularly increase.  That could be converted to a time series by discretizing the time and recording a lot of zeros in between times of actual demand.